# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I am using jboss7 server, when I am creating the client for
web-service, then facing issue, `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. And I also tried with soap UI by increasing the Socket Timeout(ms).
in proxy setting I have changed to none. then also I am facing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to ping your server?

Comment: some times only i am getting SocketTimeoutException, and most off time i am getting output

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am using SoapUI-5.3.0 (free version)

This helped me solve the issue: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Error-getting-response-java-net-SocketTimeoutException-Read/m-p/123362#M28382

Basically I forgot that i set my File > Preferences > HTTP Settings > "Socket Timeout (ms):" to 1ms. So I set it to 0 and it no longer times out.